# route_hierarchical, polymer and submenu

Tags: routes, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I was toying with the Polymer SPA example from the dartlang.org website, decided to teach it some new tricks, starting by the page fragment loading using , and now I am stuck with the submenu handling. So far the templating part of code works as expected using conditional templates, but I am stuck at routing.

So far I have modified the Page model like so:

```
class Page { 
 final String name;
 final String path;
 final String url;
 final String icon;
 final bool isDefault;
 final bool isSubmenu;
 final List<Page> subPages;

 const Page(this.name, this.path, this.url, this.icon, {this.isDefault: false, this.isSubmenu: false, this.subPages: null});
 String toString() => '$name';
}
```

and I am adding the pages into the router like this:

```
domReady() {
for (Page page in pages) {
  if (!page.isSubmenu){
    router.root.addRoute(name: page.name, path: page.path, defaultRoute: page.isDefault, enter: enterRoute);
  } else {
    for(Page subPage in page.subPages) {
      router.root.addRoute(name: subPage.name, path: subPage.path, defaultRoute: subPage.isDefault, enter: enterRoute);
    }
  }
}
router.listen();
}
```

and I am getting

```
Exception: Uncaught Error: Bad state: No element
```

exception in Dartium console.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found that the routing capabilities of route_hierarchical, used in the Polymer example are hard to work with. There's a library that's been built to make the process simpler - https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_polymer_routing .

Comment: I had a brief loog on the bwu_polymer_routing package, but even the simple example presented on the homepage seems to be pretty complicated, a little bit overkill for the simple page switching... I am looking for an easy to consume solution like the JavaScript <app-router>...

Comment: I agree, it is overly complex. Unfortunately, the way the situation stands with Dart is there's only one good routing library, and it's been developed for AngularDart. Both the polymer example and bwu_polymer_routing packages scaffold the routing library to some extent. If you want easy to use routing, consider making your app with AngularDart - its support for the routing framework is more seamless specifically because the routing framework was built as part of AngularDart.

Comment: Sure I will give an AngularDart version a try later on, I just wanted to taste the Dart Polymer flavour, and just was struck by the lack of Dart components. I like Polymer and I like Dart, so for this "project" it was a natural choice, so I am still looking into the issue...